# Google reCAPTCHA not working at all on simple implement

Tags: php, html

I have the html form looking like this:

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
  <div class="input-wrap"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i><input name="name" type="text" id="name"  class="inputForm2" onClick="this.select()" value="Name" ></div>
  <div class="input-wrap"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i><input name="email" type="text" id="email" onClick="this.select()" value="E-mail" ></div>
  <textarea name="comments" id="comments" onClick="this.select()">Message</textarea>
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="--- SITE KEY FROM GOOGLE ---" style="float: right"></div>
  <textarea name="g-recaptcha-response" id="g-recaptcha-response" style="display: none"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" id="submit"><span>Send Message</span></button>
</form>
```

And I have the mail.php like this:

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$secretkey = "--- SECRET KEY FROM GOOGLE ---";
$response = file_get_contents($url."?sectret=".$secretkey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$data = json_decode($response);

if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success == false){
    //error
    exit;
}else{
    //success
}
```

I just can't figure out where is the problem! If someone can help me out?
If I `echo` the `$data` I always receive the  `{ "success": false, "error-codes": [ "missing-input-response", "missing-input-secret" ] }` indifferent if I check the captcha form or not. I don't know why is giving me in the displayed error, also, the `"missing-input-secret"` when I give to him the secret key...

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here:

```
$response = file_get_contents($url."?sectret=".$secretkey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Should be:

```
$response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$secretkey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Comment: Yes you are right! This happends when you are tired... Thank you very much for that. Now the "missing-input-secret" error is eliminated, but the "missing-input-response" and "success": false is persist!

Comment: @styven can you do a `var_dump($_POST);` ?

Comment: This is what I got: `array(3) { ["name"]=> string(6) "dfgfhg" ["email"]=> string(16) "fhgjghjh@gtgt.ol" ["comments"]=> string(14) "nghhgjhkjhkjlj" }`

Comment: What do you think @FMashiro? Why the `g-recaptcha-response` is missing and the form is not sending it to mail.php?

Comment: did you hardcode the div with the `g-recaptcha-response`?

Comment: @styven I mean, is this: `<textarea name="g-recaptcha-response">` in your HTML or is that only there when you use the debugging console

Comment: That `textarea` is always in my form, not only in the debugging console.

Comment: Or this is a more complex implementation that is generating the `textarea` only in console? I just copy paste it from other site. Maybe that's why is not `POST` it in mail.php? Please if you can, help me out with this. I realy can't figure out were is the problem.

Comment: You should follow google's guide for implementing it. Not copy paste it from another site. This is probably why it fails.

Comment: I followed, but I can't understand it so well, there is so poor instructions on they tutorial...

Comment: Is a problem if I'm not loading the script using the HTTPS protocol? My site is only HTTP.